# the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have mac installed in my PC. I am running my xamarin project in Device.that is running fine.but when one of my teammate trying to deploy project in device that is connected to my PC.He is connected to my mac in VS.but it gives such error

```
the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```

anyone have idea about this.please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848622/codesign-allocate-error-unable-to-find-utility-codesign-allocate-not-a-deve

Comment: i have gone thought that link.but not get idea.and where should i run that commands?in cmd it is not valid commands

Comment: `codesign_allocate` is an Xcode tools, it would exist on the Mac not the PC. You can use `Terminal` to access a shell and determine from that SO question if you have multiple codesign_allocate and if one is "old"

Comment: ok.got it.thank you @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

I tried most everything in [codesign_allocate: error: unable to find utility "codesign_allocate", not a developer tool or in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848622/codesign-allocate-error-unable-to-find-utility-codesign-allocate-not-a-deve) and none of the answers at this time worked for my machine.

I had to take the nuclear option (use with caution):

- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/`
- Uninstall Xcode
- Fresh install from App Store