# Xcode 10 error on High Sierra "Executable requires at least macOS 10.14"

Tags: xcode, macos-high-sierra

I have Xcode 10.2.1 working successfully on High Sierra (10.13.6), because this machine does not support Mojave, even with the Mojave patcher tool.

I can successfully start and build new projects, but my main project (which was created in Xcode 10 w/ Mojave originally) when I build I receive this error towards the very end:

```
unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
Executable requires at least macOS 10.14, but is being run on macOS 10.13.6, and so is exiting.codesign_allocate
```

I have tried both setting the xcode-select path to:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer
```

None of them worked :( And I must get it building in High Sierra somehow, because I won't have access to Mojave for awhile until I can purchase a new machine. :( Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848622/codesign-allocate-error-unable-to-find-utility-codesign-allocate-not-a-deve

Comment: I came across that thread earlier, and it didn't seem it applied since it doesn't have to deal with xcodebuild requiring Mojave, but I will try it out anyways, and report back. Thanks! @jvarela

Comment: @jvarela, just gave it a shot, didn't work. My codesign_allocate is located just fine 

Comment: What is the setting of the minimum macOS for your project?

Comment: How do I check the minimum for a project @jvarela

Comment: Open your project, then go to the navigator pane on the left top corner, click on the project icon to see its settings. You should check that the project and the target minimum MacOS is 10.13 and not higher.

Comment: @jvarela I set the target to 10.13, still doesn't build :(

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Xcode on your disk? If so, delete them all, except the instance you want to use. Sometimes the dev tools can become “confused” by that. If that does not help either then I would delete all instances and reinstall the Xcode version you want to use.

Comment: Yes I tried that :( @jvarela

Comment: Then try to reset the paths by using xcode-select -r. If that does not work check if you are using any code that requires macOS 10.14. For example, check what SDK is your project targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue using Xcode v10.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and could not get an older iOS app have to build and run in the Simulator.app setup within Xcode 10.2

All that said, I do have two parallel Xcode installs on my High Sierra box, ie. Xcode v10.1 and v10.2

I can launch each Xcode version independently, and am able to launch Xcode 10.1 and build and run the app using Xcode 10.1 and the provided simulator for Xcode 10.1 which is helpful because I build this app against the 9.3.5 SDK iOS.